# non interactive bash script: ignore File on system created by you or by a script

Tags: bash

I've created a config file before installing logstash.
When I install logstash I face:

```
Configuration file '/etc/logstash/pipelines.yml'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** pipelines.yml (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? D
```

I just want to keep the `N (default)` option but I prefer to specify it then just ignore it because it's default.

How can I do this. My command just was

```
sudo apt-get install logstash
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 $ sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" -y install logstash
```